# Fetch the prepared query with parameteres filled

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, prepared-statement, micronaut-data

We are using Micronaut JPA Data with Hibernate.

We have a dynamic criteria builder and we want to generate SQL statement based on that.

Using that SQL query either we need to verify the query and/or execute the query in a different DB/server we don't have control over.

Hibernate provides a way to derive the prepared statement and that can be retrieved, but it does not have all the parameters included. **So is there a way to fetch the final query that can be executed in DB directly?** Currently we have to get the prepared statement and fill all the question marks manually.

`SQLExtractor` Can be used to extract the query but we need to extract query with parameter filled or any other way where we get parameter as list.

Please note that we are using CriteraBuilder for the predicates, we are  using multiple roots and hence cross join (with where condition which makes it inner join) and predicates in main and joined tables too.

we are using `hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=inline` as well

Example
Created a repo [here](https://github.com/akshayvadher/hibernate-prepared-statement-full-query)

```java
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id private Integer id;

  private String name;
}
// and
@Entity
public class Cycle {
  @Id private Integer id;


  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private CycleType type;

  private LocalDate created;
}
// and 
public enum CycleType {
  A
}
```

```java
    var cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
    root.alias("user");

    Path<String> name = root.get("name");
    Predicate first = cb.equal(name.as(String.class), "a");
    Path<Integer> id = root.get("id");

    Root<Cycle> subRoot = query.from(Cycle.class);
    subRoot.alias("cycle");
    Path<Integer> subPath = subRoot.get("id");
    Predicate second = cb.equal(id.as(Integer.class), subPath.as(Integer.class));

    Path<CycleType> subName = subRoot.get("type");
    Predicate third = cb.equal(subName.as(CycleType.class), A);

    Path<LocalDate> subCreated = subRoot.get("created");
    Predicate fourth = cb.equal(subCreated.as(LocalDate.class), LocalDate.now());

    Predicate restrictions = cb.and(first, second, third, fourth);

    CriteriaQuery<User> where = query.select(root).where(restrictions);

    TypedQuery<User> userTypedQuery = em.createQuery(where).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(10);

    String sql = SQLExtractor.from(userTypedQuery);
    log.info("Query: {}", sql);

    return userTypedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

The SQLExtractor.from returns following

```sql
select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_ from user user0_ cross join cycle cycle1_ where user0_.name='a' and user0_.id=cycle1_.id and cycle1_.type=? and cycle1_.created=?
```

Here we need some way to get SQL with `?` filled or list of parameters that can be filled to `?`

Expectation

```sql
select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_ from user user0_ cross join cycle cycle1_ where user0_.name='a' and user0_.id=cycle1_.id and cycle1_.type='A' and cycle1_.created='2022-10-31'
```

Comment: I would guess you are using prepared statements and parameter binding to the JDBC statement (vs inline in the SQL statement) as they avoid risks from SQL injection attacks. I don't think Hibernate offers to inline parameters, so you'll have to do value replacement anyway.

Comment: Not prepared statement, I am using JPA criteria query. Example added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the bind values from the Hibernate `QueryParameters`, but this is no easy task and also, replacing parameter markers with literals is type dependent. So doing this kind of thing in a general way is not easy.

Why do you even need that? I'd suggest you to stick to parameter markers, as that also improves the statement cache hit rate.

Comment: We need to take the query and send it to some server (different lang) that executes the same query to a replica DB

Comment: Since you are using JPA Criteria, you can use `hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=inline` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-query) to tell Hibernate to inline parameters. That way, you should be able to generate a SQL statement that you can send over to that application.

Comment: Tried that as well, it didn't work. Is it because I am using criteria builder and multiple roots? I updated the question as well.

Comment: There are tests for this in the Hibernate testsuite to verify it works, so it must be a configuration issue on your side. This config option must be specified in the `hibernate.properties` or `persistence.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated the question, got the issue, the string literal works but things like ENUM or Date does not work.

Comment: Hibernate 5 has no support for temporal literals. The enum rendering is probably just an oversight, but these limitations won't be fixed in 5. Hibernate 6 definitely doesn't suffer from these limitations though. If you set the property `hibernate.criteria.value_handling_mode` to `inline` on Hibernate 6 it will inline everything as literal, unless passed explicitly as parameter.